# Is there any way to make a multiplayer game in unity completely free?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

Hello so am wondering if there is any way to create a multiplayer game completely free, Like I followed Brackeys tutorials using UNet to create a multiplayer game, I followed the whole tutorials till I reached part 17 which is about matchmaking He went to unity dashboard and to multiplayer he said that there is free server that you can make but with 20 CCU But In 2022 Is it removed?
Please it is very important, is there any tutorials on youtube or anywhere In Internet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use Photon Pun 2 it's easy to setup and free up to 20CCU

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/pun-2-free-119922

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a multiplayer API built into Unity directly. You'll need to import a few packages, but Unity provides sample projects and some tutorials [here](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/).